# multiple GSS providers in golang pgconn?

Tags: postgresql, go, kerberos

Let's imagine I have to connect to postgres using kerberos mupltiple times in one application. Recently kerberos support has been added to pgconn and pgx packages, but there is one limitation to that. We need to define a gss provider globally, like so:

```golang
func init() {
    pgconn.RegisterGSSProvider(func() (pgconn.GSS, error) {
        return gopgkrb5.NewGSS()
    })
}
```

If I want to use different TGT's (or keytabs, doesn't matter) for multiple connections, it pretty much seems impossible now. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I decided to just change provider before every new connection, as it is just a global variable inside pgconn package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).